# HttpURLConnection returns normal unicode symbols only when run inside java studio(Intellij Idea)

Tags: http, javafx, unicode, utf

When I compile to jar it returns different symbols but in the Intellij it runs perfect as I need.

```
URL url = new URL("http://myurl.here/file.php");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String line;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(line);
}
in.close();
```

After this I add the result to Javafx Label. Here it shows perfect before compiling.

Comment: how do you output the result? Could it just be that the console you write to does not support utf-8?

Comment: I set the result to Label (javafx) but after compiling it doesn't show utf

Comment: different machines? so that the default encoding might be different?

Comment: @rdmueller the same machine.

Comment: can you add some more code or point to an example repository so that it would be easier to reproduce the problem?

Comment: btw: did you try to track it down by for instance directly setting the label to some utf characters in ider to see if it is a problem with the label or with the httpURLConnection?

Comment: is it both the same jre?

Comment: @rdmueller This is the only code that works with this text for Label (and I just set the text using label.setText). 
Yes, if I set the text using code it shows fine. 
And IntellijIdea uses jdk 1.8, and my system should use jre 1.8... I don't think it is the problem because jdk is just a toolkit to run on jre.

The same jar? I click 'run' in my project to run it directly without compiling to output directory  and it works perfect. But not after compiling artefacts(jar)...

Comment: I asked about the jre because it could have been that you use different vendors. So, the code is the same, the environments are different. I guess you have to find this difference to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woah... I tried another ways and this works perfect! :D

```
URL url = new URL("http://url/file.php");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
String input;
String line = "";
while((input=br.readLine()) !=null){
    line = line + input;
}
```